# Return job titles from Get-ADUser that match csv

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to import job titles from a csv file into Powershell then use the `Get-ADUser` to return all active users with those titles and then export to a new csv

Can someone please help?

```
$csvjobtitle = Import-Csv -Header csvTitle -Path c:\Job_titles.csv

Get-ADUser -Filter {enabled -eq "true" -and Title -eq "$csvjobtitle"} -
Properties SamAccountName, GivenName, Surname, EmailAddress, Title | select 
SamAccountName, GivenName, Surname, EmailAddress, Title | Export-CSV "C:\Ad 
Extract.csv"
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current code?

Comment: You have more than one item in your `Job_titles.csv`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible solution:

```
$csvjobtitle = (Import-Csv -Header csvTitle -Path c:\Job_titles.csv).'csvTitle'

$csvjobtitle | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADUser -Filter {enabled -eq "true" -and Title -eq "$_"} -Properties SamAccountName, GivenName, Surname, EmailAddress, Title | Select SamAccountName, GivenName, Surname, EmailAddress, Title
} | Export-CSV "C:\Ad Extract.csv"
```

There are two changes to your previous code:

1. We get back just the 'csvTitle' values from the CSV, rather than an object which has a csvTitle property.
2. We loop through those values with a `ForEach-Object` loop which gets the AD user for each title (where the current title is represented via `$_`).

Because `ForEach-Object` supports the pipeline (and our `Get-ADUser` cmdlet returns its result to the pipeline), we can simply pipe the results of the `ForEach-Object` to `Export-CSV`.